# How do I detect where the program is stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, infinite-loop, freeze

I am working on a (relatively complex) game. The game freezes in release mode. The freeze happens after 1-2 min. of game-play. The current configuration of the release mode that I have allows me to break (that is go into debug), which is good, but may give me wrong information but that is fine for this particular case (I can turn off the optimization for a single file/function/code).

Problem is, I (we, since we are a team) don't know where it is hanging. It is not as simple as one relatively small infinite loop that is hanging, as other things (Graphics, sound) are being updated, just that the game-play has stalled. The main game loop (an infinite loop) is always running and is very long/complex, so stepping through is going to be a pain (but it is one of the options).

The first thing I tried is Visual Studio's `break all` but it always breaks in code that is not mine and consequently shows me assembly output. Eventually, with enough persistence, SVN history checking and commenting out code I will be able to figure out where it is hanging, but there has to be a better way... hopefully?

**Note:** There is a Visual Studio option I am aware of that allows *debugging user code only*, but that is managed code only.

**EDIT:** Was able to solve the problem via stack trace and lots of hours of keeping track of various things to see where the game is *hanging*. I will select Sjoerd's answer as the correct one, however, if someone has a suggestion for a tool/technique that allows to *automate* such a task, by all means, add your answer!

Comment: maybe is not an infinite loop but a call that is blocking forever. have you looked for blocking i/o calls?

Comment: yes, it is not blocking i/o... I don't know how else to put it that is why I said `infinite loop` but it is not a `loop` really, it is stuck in some `state` and I wish to find out which functions are (or may are NOT) running...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you break and you encounter native code that is not yours, check the **call stack**. The call stack is the list of functions that got called to reach the current point in the code. Go up some levels in the stack until you encounter the method which is currently running.

Comment: Right. I did not mention this, but the call stack displays different portions of the code every time (for example, graphics/physics/sound). Like I said, I can keep on doing it the hard way, and eventually I'll figure out where I made the mistake, but I am looking for a better way.

Comment: But there should be a common denominator somewhere in the stack, the part which is hung up. Also, if the code is multi-threaded, remember to check all the threads (little dropdown in the toolbox)

Comment: @carlpett: That is exactly what I am doing right now, but I hoped there would a more automated way of doing it (maybe VS or a 3rd part program telling me the percentage execution of each function... very close to a profiler, but not quite as the profilers I tried literally stall the game)

Answer (score 4):

Hit the pause button in Visual Studio while the program is hung.

This should break the debugger at the current line. You can then step through and see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to debugging symbols and breaks (which is the tool of choice when possible), add logging: It is not uncommon for games (and other apps) to have a huge logging system they can turn on and off with a compiler flag so they can still do some kind of debugging/tracing in "release builds". If your logging works fine you should see what is and what is not happening and get at least some idea where things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You might well never be able to catch the problem via an interrupt if the code that should be executing isn't executing. There are lots of ways this can happen. Just a few:

- You have some parameter that indicates the time at which the next update is to be performed. If this somehow gets set to some big number, the code that does the update will happily see that nothing needs to be done. Next! This can give all the appearances of a hung program even though it isn't really hung at all. The state update and the graphics functions are still being called at their prescribed rate.
- You may some counter that represents time and some rounding mechanism for incrementing time. If the counter is a 32 bit signed int and the granularity of your counter is 0.1 microseconds, you will hit INT32_MAX after just 3.6 minutes. Now time is frozen, so once again you have a situation where updates may not be performed.
- You are using a single precision floating point number to represent time and update time via `time += delta_t;` This will stop working after a couple of minutes if your `delta_t` is 10 microseconds. This is yet another mechanism by which time can be frozen.

**Edit**
Have you looked at the CPU usage in your various threads? The above problems might cause the physics or game-playing thread to exhibit a drastic drop in CPU usage after a couple of minutes. You might also get this behavior if the game playing thread is perpetually locked, but here you might (with the right tool) get an indication that that thread is always asleep.

Comment: Good suggestions (+1). It is definitely not something wrong with game time however as the game ran perfectly fine for a long time until the last few updates. Problem is, nobody tested the game for that long until too many updates were applied and then later found out this is happening.